# Is "How to make shotguns practical again" on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I was thinking about asking how I can make shotguns practical in the military outside of a military police context but I think it might be a bit overly broad. Would you agree with this assessment and if so is there some way to narrow it down a bit?

Comment: It's very hard (if not practically impossible) to say if a question will be too broad or not based on a one-sentence summary. However, you can use the question sandbox to get early feedback on the question that you have in mind. The sandbox isn't perfect, but it's usually a reasonably good way to iron out the worst wrinkles before a question gets posted on the main site.